# Proper way to tell InlfuxDB client (or any Python request client) to trust a self-signed cert?

Tags: python, ssl, influxdb

I'm using the [Python InfluxDB client library](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python), but my Influx DB instance uses a self-signed certificate.

I keep getting `InsecureRequestWarning`s because I have to turn `INFLUXDB_VERIFY_SSL` to false in my Flask config.

It seems that the InfluxDB client library is connecting to InfluxDB via the `requests` library under-the-hood. What's the lowest friction way to tell this library, or the requests library underneath it, or my Flask application in general, to trust a self-signed cert?

I'd rather not:

• create a new certificate bundle of every single cert that should be trusted

I'd rather:

• have a one-liner somewhere, pointing to a specific self-signed cert that my requests library should trust